# what does this stad for [ 4200.237911 ] in i/o buffer error?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

When i try to mount an external HDD of a friend of mine,this error is all over my screen.It shows a lot of errors which are unfamiliar to me ,but onething i know , it has many bad sectors in it.

I have ran into these errors pretty often.I have seen this whenever i tried to mount a faulty or bad or storage device.But it never occured to me until recently that what does these numbers represent in the error i.e [ 4200.237911 ] i.e what does they try to convey ?

> does this represent any sector no: or anything similar ? Is there any particular name for this [4200.237911 ] ? I wanted to know more about it since i occasionally ran into this (even though unmounting the disk will solve the problem).can anybody enlighten me on this topic ?

atlast what does i/o buffer error stand for ?

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a time stamp. It's not relevant to the error itself.

To my understanding, it displays the seconds since the system was rebooted.

Comment: i assume that the number after the "." stands for  seconds after reboot.but i booted the system before 3hrs or so.also what does no: on the left of  "." shows ?

Comment: @DEFCON1: The value before the `.` are the seconds, the value after the `.` are the fraction of seconds.